# How to let the matcher to match the second invocation on mock?

Tags: mocking, testng, mockito

I have an interface like this

```
 public interface EventBus{
     public void fireEvent(GwtEvent<?> event);
 }
```

and test code(testng method) looks like this:

```
    @Test
    public void testFireEvent(){

          EventBus mock=mock(EventBus.class);

          //when  both Event1 and Event2 are subclasses of GwtEvent<?>
          mock.fireEvent(new Event1());
          mock.fireEvent(new Event2());

          //then
         verify(mock).fireEvent(argThat(new Event2Matcher()));

    }
```

Event2Matcher looks like this:

```
private class Event2Matcher extends ArgumentMatcher<Event2>
{
  @Override
  public boolean matches(Object arg)
  {
       return ((Event2) arg).getSth==sth;
  }
}
```

But get an error indicating that:

```
    Event1 can't be cast to Event2
```

And obviously,the matcher matched the first invoking

```
    mock.fireEvent(new Event1());
```

So,the statement within matcher

```
return ((Event2) arg).getSth==sth;
```

Will throw out this exception.So the question is how to let

```
  verify(mock).fireEvent(argThat(new Event2Matcher()));
```

to match the second invoking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `matches()` method returns a boolean to indicate whether it matches. All you need to do is make sure that you return false if the argument is irrelevant, before you try to cast.

I would do so with a short-circuit, as here:

```
private class Event2Matcher extends ArgumentMatcher<Event2> {
  @Override public boolean matches(Object arg) {
    return arg instanceof Event2 && ((Event2) arg).getSth==sth;
  }
}
```

...or extend the [`TypeSafeMatcher` in the Hamcrest package](https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/source/browse/branches/hamcrest-java-gwt/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/TypeSafeMatcher.java) instead, which does a null check and a cast for you. (There's a similar class [included in JUnit since 4.5](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.5/org/junit/internal/matchers/TypeSafeMatcher.java#TypeSafeMatcher), though it's in an internal package.)